# Set value into object with function (java script)

Tags: javascript, object

When I used getFullName, getFirstName and getLastName work ok, but I can't use set functions setFullName, setLastName, setFirstName. My code:

```
var Person = function(firstAndLast) {
    var fn=firstAndLast.split(' ');
    var fstr=fn.join(' ');
    var frn=fn[0];
    var lsn=fn[1];

    this.getFullName=function(){return fstr;};
    this.getFirstName=function(){return frn;};
    this.getLastName=function(){return lsn;};
    this.setFirstName=function(a){fn[0]=a;};
    this.setLastName=function(b){fn[1]=b;};
    this.setFullName=function(c){fn=c.split(' ');};

};
```

Comment: You're setting  `fn[0]`, not `frn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
var Person = function(firstAndLast) {
    var self = this;
    this.fn = firstAndLast.split(' ');
    this.frn = this.fn[0];
    this.lsn = this.fn[1];

    this.getFullName=function(){return self.fn.join(' ');};
    this.getFirstName=function(){return self.frn;};
    this.getLastName=function(){return self.lsn;};
    this.setFirstName=function(a){self.frn=a; self.fn[0]=a;};
    this.setLastName=function(b){self.lsn=b; self.fn[1]=b;};
    this.setFullName=function(c){
        self.fn = c.split(' '); 
        self.frn = this.fn[0];
        self.lsn = this.fn[1];};
};
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5v1np56z/)

If you have a lot of `Person` objects, you should consider moving the `getter`/`setter` functions to the [class prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype):

```
var Person = function(firstAndLast) {
    this.fn = firstAndLast.split(' ');
    this.frn = this.fn[0];
    this.lsn = this.fn[1];
};

Person.prototype.getFullName = function() {
    return this.fn.join(' ');
}

Person.prototype.getFirstName = function() {
    return this.lsn;
}

Person.prototype.getLastName = function() {
    return this.lsn;
}

Person.prototype.setFirstName = function(a) {
    this.frn=a; 
  this.fn[0]=a;
}

Person.prototype.setLastName = function(b) {
    this.lsn=b;
  this.fn[1]=b;
}

Person.prototype.setFullName = function(c) {
  this.fn = c.split(' '); 
  this.frn = this.fn[0];
  this.lsn = this.fn[1];
}
```

See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5v1np56z/1/)